# Angular JS - How to call a function of a module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and have to fix bugs of my collegue. I found this factory with functions. How can I put a reset_All-function that calls the reset-function of all modules ?

```
.factory('MyCollection', function() {
    return {

        resetAll: function(projectId) {

          // call the reset-function of SomeController

        }
    }
})



.controller('SomeController', function($scope, a) {


    $scope.reset = function() {
        ...........
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent tight coupling of the different modules, you can broadcast an event and catch it in the respective controllers:

```
.factory('MyCollection', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        resetAll: function(projectId) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('reset');
        }
    };
}]);

.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'a', function($scope, a) {
    $scope.reset = function() {
        // do something here
    }; 

    $scope.$on('reset', function() {
        $scope.reset();
    });
}]);
```

To learn about Angular's events have a look at [Understanding Angular’s $scope and $rootScope event system $emit, $broadcast and $on](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to *depend* on `MyCollection`, so you can inject it:

```
.controller('SomeController', [ '$scope', 'a', 'MyCollection',
    function ($scope, a, MyCollection) {


    $scope.reset = function(id) {
        MyCollection.resetAll(id)
    }

 }]);
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to read.

Comment: Downvote reason: Does not answer the question, he wants to invoke $scope.reset from MyCollection, not the other way around.

Comment: Not to be "that guy" but your correction actually made it worse, you cannot inject a controller and 'MyCollection' is actually a factory. Dennis Traubs solution seem like the way to go for doing what the question was about.